# i am co-buyer on auto loan

Tags: car, will

the buyer is deceased and the title is in his name.  I am co-buyer on paperwork with finance co.  Can anyone make claim on car if he willed it to me?

Comment: This seems like more of a legal question than a personal finance one.

Comment: What do you mean by "Make a claim" If he willed it to you, then it would be your car. Whether or not you were on the loan paperwork is irrelevant. You are a co-borrower, not a co-buyer. Meaning you will pay the note regardless of whether you end up with the car.